# cron/ bash is not working via scripting, scoping issue?

Tags: bash, debian, ubuntu, cron, configuration

I'm trying to schedule a task to run ever minute using cron:

`* * * * * /home/yzm/simple.sh >> /var/log/cron.log`

and this returns: `bash: yzm: command not found`

cd-ing out of that folder:

`cd .. 
* * * * * /home/yzm/simple.sh >> /var/log/cron.log`

returns:
`bash: bin: command not found`

I've verified that the script works when just executing over terminal: `sh /home/yzm/simple.sh`

I'm not sure what I need to do to get this working.  Whenever I try to run the crontab command, it seems to just take the first entry in the current directory and output "command not found".

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to *run the crontab entry* in a terminal, instead of editing the crontab file using `crontab -e`. So the shell is expanding the `*`s to list of files and directories (first those in your `/home`  where it finds your home dir then, after you `cd ..`, in `/`, starting with `/bin`) and trying to run the list as a sequence of shell commands.

Comment: @steeldriver I think that should be an answer, really.

Comment: `crontab -l` returns:
`* * * * * /bin/echo "doge" >> /home/yzm/asdf`
which isnt working as well, so I'm not sure as to how to proceed..

Comment: Does the script have execute perm?

Comment: how should you provide permissions for cron?

I don't know if cron properly resolves paths so I try to point directly to the bin to run the command `/usr/bin/git` it also doesnt seem to have permissions to cd `cd /var/www/site`

Answer (score 0):

I changed permissions to the script and the script: `chmod u+x /path/to/script.sh` and was able to execute the script.  I'm not sure if it was necessary to change to root user, but I changed to root throughout the process